# PDF inside iFrame not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, pdf, iframe

I have been trying to display PDF inside iFrame, it works well for all other browsers and platforms but not working with iOS. When I tried to access in chrome/Safari in iPhone/iPad, it shows the first page BUT does not allow to scroll down the PDF. And when it comes to HTML inside iFrame, it works perfectly, per my observation it looks like issue is with PDF inside iFrame on iOS. Tried all the links provided on various websites, overflow-auto, webkit scrolling, scrolling only y axis, position absolute/relative increasing the height which results in white pages and all other possible solutions, but no luck yet. The language of implementation is ASP.NET-C# where I am setting the iFrame source dynamically. Below is the source through which I am trying to achieve above task.

```
<div id="wrapper" class="Sales-container container">
    <iframe runat="server" id="Contents" class="myiframe" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" />        
</div>


.Sales-container{position:absolute !important;width:100%}

.container{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;padding-left:7px;padding-right:8px}

.myiframe{z-index:0;white-space:nowrap}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need https, you can use the google docs viewer

make the src http://docs.google.com/gview?url=YOURADDRESSHERE&embedded=true

If that won't work for you, I'm currently looking into pdf.js

Comment: OMG thanks a lot, not only does this provide the required functionality on iOS, but also makes a cohesive experience across browsers. Didn't know Google Docs was able to do that :D

Comment: *Pro tip for anyone looking for help in the future* When using a url retrieved from Firebase storage, yo first need to encode it with `encodeURIComponent(url)`

Comment: In the absence of the absolute URL of the pdf, this solution does not work in iPad browsers. Please let me know if there is any solution when there are pdfs serving from the APIs.